# Getting to an unknown type's method and run it c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an abstract class (Parent) with a function called funcA.
Parent has 4 childern and the user needs to choose which one to access.
What I need to do is to access the overrided method funcA in the child subclass that was chosen by the user and activate it.

Parent:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
 public string PropA {get; set;}
 public string PropB {get; set;}
 public DateTime PropC {get; set;}
 public DateTime PropD {get; set;}

 public abstract void FuncA();

}
```

Child:

```
public class ChildA: Parent
{
   public string PropE {get; set;}
   public string PropF {get; set;}

   public override void FuncA()
   {
     // Some Code
   }
}
```

Main:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Enter the type of child: ");
  string type = Console.Readline();

  // I need to identify which child is type, access that child's FuncA and
  // run it.
}
```

The string type is validated as an existing child. There is no way the user enters a type that does not exist.

Comment: Use reflection? `Type t = Type.GetType(thatType); t.GetMethod("FuncA").Invoke(...);`

Comment: I tried, but Invoke demands an object to perform the method on. All I have is the type and I can't create an object of an unknown type.

Comment: @EinatLugassy You _can't_ or you _don't know how to_?

Comment: @DStanley I tried but it's always possible that there is a way I don't know of, I couldn't find a way to create a new object using the 'new' keywork or using GetType().

Comment: Show what you've tried so the _real_ problem can be identified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're *always* calling the abstract method you can just cast the object to a `Parent` and call the method in a type-safe manner:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("ChildA");
Parent p = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Parent;
p.FuncA();
```

Since `FuncA` is virtual, the most derived implementation will be used.